# How to fix 404 not found after submitting the request to the auth controller login of laravel

Tags: laravel

this is my first to encounter this problem, where after I submit the request in the Auth Controller login, The requested URL /internalcommunication/login was not found on this server. I already tried the other reference from the other users, however it not works for me. to be more understandable, I will show my structure.

```
Laravel Version: "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
```

**Main Target: After successfully login it will redirect to the / or index page.**

**Note: I already setup the project path to the document root of the apache.**

**I have my route list:**

[image: Route List]

**My Html Blade:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<center><h4>Sign In Your Account!</h4></center>

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
  @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

        @error('email')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

        @error('password')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input  type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1"/>
        <label class="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {{ __('Login') }}
    </button>
</form>
```

**Error:**

[image: Error]

Comment: It looks like an incorrect APP_URL in your .env. Is the APP_URL equal to your domain you are using to build?

Comment: yes i already set it my domain to the app_url

Comment: your server isn't configured properly (in some way) it seems  ... the request should be handed off to laravel and it looks like that isn't happening, often due to rewrite not being setup properly

Comment: after change the url run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: the `APP_URL` is only for console commands and there should be no reason to run `config:clear` since there is no reason to cache the config while in development